# Laravel Menu issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the code below to read my menu items from a model, loaded from a DB. I need to set them active based on the current URL.
This code only works for the root '/' it doesn't work for others, even though if I echo out the values, `url($menu->link)` and `Request::url()` they are the same.

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
    <li>
        <a href="{{url($menu->link) }}" @if(Request::is($menu->link))  class="active" @endif>
            <span class="glyphicon {{ $menu->icon }}"></span>
                {{ $menu->title }}
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the `$menu->link` look like and how does your route definition look like?

Comment: They are identical to the `Request::url()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `$menu->link` will return a string that look like `posts`, `/posts/edit`, etc...

If that is the case, you can do

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
    <li>
        <a href="{{url($menu->link) }}" @if(url()->current() == url($menu->link))  class="active" @endif>
            <span class="glyphicon {{ $menu->icon }}"></span>
                {{ $menu->title }}
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```